# Bamboo Docker build Errors with Google Container Registry

Tags: docker, bamboo, google-container-registry

I'm attempting to run a Bamboo (private server) task that builds a docker image. The dockerfile builds from an image on google container registry. gcr.io/project-name/image-name:tag. However, whenever my task is triggered, I get a build error.

Checking the log, the issue appears to be:

```
build   23-Aug-2018 20:08:52    Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
build   23-Aug-2018 20:08:52    
build   23-Aug-2018 20:08:52    Step 1 : FROM gcr.io/project-name/image-name:tag
build   23-Aug-2018 20:08:52    Trying to pull repository gcr.io/project-name/image-name ... 
build   23-Aug-2018 20:08:52    Pulling repository gcr.io/project-name/image-name
error   23-Aug-2018 20:08:52    Error: Status 405 trying to pull repository project-name/image-name: "v1 Registry API is disabled. If you are not explicitly using the v1 Registry API, it is possible your v2 image could not be found. Verify that your image is available, or retry with `dockerd --disable-legacy-registry`. See https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support/deprecation-notices"
simple  23-Aug-2018 20:08:52    Failing task since return code of [/usr/bin/docker build --no-cache=true --force-rm=true --tag=gcr.io/project-name/out_image-name:outer_tag /var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/3997697/AN-CA-JOB1] was 149 while expected 0
```

Looking into the error, I came across [this google troubleshooting page](http://[https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support]), which suggests confirming the names are right. Running the command, I can confirm the name returns results.

Additionally, the "retry with `dockerd --disable-legacy-registry`" suggestion seems dated, since the Docker docs say:

> The disable-legacy-registry configuration option has been removed and,
>   when used, will produce an error on daemon startup.

What am I doing wrong?

Other details:

- Bamboo version 6.4.1 build 60405

Comment: What version of docker are you using? disable-legacy-registry is gone for versions < 17.06, I think.

Also, can we check the docker daemon logs. Even better if you can set the log level to debug mode.

Comment: Not sure about the docker version. Is there a way for me to check if I'm not an admin? There's a snippet of the logs in the question above, but before that point it's mostly just a really long list of environment variables - is there a shorter section I can post that would be relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue is an outdated version of Docker.